# Formik material ui with autocomplete not works as expected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup

I'm using **formik** with **material-ui** to build custom autocomplete component.

[my link to code](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-payne-4etovu?file=/src/App.tsx)

I add validation using **yup** for autocomplete to be required (user need to select one option):

```
 validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
      skill: Yup.object().shape({
        value: Yup.string().required(),
        label: Yup.string().required()
      })
    }),
```

when user select any option I want it to save the option as {label,value} and not just the value because then I need to send it as object to the server.

I get some errors:

1. when I press submit I get error

   `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {value, label}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`
2. I get those warnings:

   > MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid. None of the options match with `{"label":"","value":""}`. You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test.

   > Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `helperText` supplied to `ForwardRef(TextField)`, expected a ReactNode.

I'm trying to build reusable autocomplete component to be able to get the selected value as {label,value} without any error and working as expected.
I'm not sure if my validation is the right way. I want just the user to select an option.

in addition, I would like to ask, can I store object details into the value not as string? if no, what the best way to store value of object as option?

is my yup schema is the right way? should I store id of object as value and then filter it? how to pass value as string to autocomplete and show it selected in autocomplete?
How can I do it without skill schema as object, just as string like:

```
 validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
  skill: Yup.string().required()
}),
```

Comment: If you want {lable, value} on submit then you need to use a filter and filter out your required object and then set it on the state....
const reqSkill = skills.filter(res=>res.value === <You need to put value that you are getting onSubmit>)....

Comment: @ShahVipul can you see my new issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74937539/formik-autocomplete-filter-and-reset-fields-based-on-other-fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because initial value as {label:'' , value :''} is not in skills list. so in isOptionEqualToValue it will return false

simply remove isOptionEqualToValue prop and in value check if there is option with that value and if not set null

```
  const getValueFromOptions = (value: string) => {
    return (
      options.find((option: any) => option.value === value) ?? null
    );
  };
```

and in auto complete :

```
<Autocomplete
     
      value={getValueFromOptions(field.value)}
    ...
```

or check if field.value has value otherwise null

```
  <Autocomplete
         
      value={Boolean(field.value?.value) ? field.value : null}
    ...
```

and another error was from show error message because meta.error is object that contains value and label error  so you need to show one of them, I changed it to this :

```
renderInput={(params) => {

        const errorMsg = meta.error as { value?:string }

        return (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label={label}
            name={name}
            error={showError}
            helperText={meta.touched && errorMsg?.value}
          />
        );
      }}
```

and another error was from show error message, it was displaying 'skill.value is a required field' so I simply add new message in yup validation

```
validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
      skill: Yup.object().shape({
        value: Yup.string().required('skill is a required field'),
        label: Yup.string()
      })
    }),
```

you see pure code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-nova-nqvxq2?file=/src/components/AutocompleteField.tsx

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250396/discussion-on-answer-by-ali-sattarzadeh-formik-material-ui-with-autocomplete-not).

Comment: Hey Ali, when I have some autocompletes in my code, I press submit button, only the first autocomplete is touched and show the error message but the other not touched and not show the error.. when I change the order of initial values only the one in the top show the error message after submit.. it's the same validation schema for all of them.. I tried to do it with your example but in your example it works good. https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-albattani-9dwhdg

Comment: Hi, got it , now you wanna make it work with your way?

Comment: Hi, I want it to work as expected, one I press on submit and all fields not valid, I want it to show the error message under each field.. in the link I added it works fine, but in my code (in my laptop project) it works weird (our code looks little bit as the same).. do you have any idea?

Comment: aha it's hard to imagine what's happening. could you please tell me  what are the differences ?

Comment: actually it's long code, but I can describe what I see. when I separate my code and add custom components with custom fields, I add two autocomplete components in same parent, they kind of brothers, so only the first "brother" is show as touched..\

Comment: it's happen only in autocomplete field custom, when I add textfield it's works as expected. that's my autocomplete component field: https://pastecode.io/s/4bnitkcz

Comment: actually I got a little confused.
is your initialValues dymanic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250553/discussion-between-manspof-and-ali-sattarzadeh).

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh can you see my new issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74937539/react-query-refetch-even-if-they-key-exist-in-cache

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I wasn't online @Manspof