# React query refetch even if the key already exist in cache

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, react-query

I built a form using react,react-query, material ui,  formik and yup (for schema validation).

[link to the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-autocomplete-forked-zcf11t?file=/src/App.tsx)

**I built custom fields:**

- SelectField
- AutocompleteField
- CacheAutocompleteField - cache field using react-query

  - queryAsyncFunc props - get async function and cache the data using react-query

**I have 3 fields:**

- Type - Select field
- Country - CacheAutocompleteField
- City - CacheAutocompleteField

**My scenario:**

I select any type from my hardcoded list (Type A, Type B , Type C),

I search any country, then I search any city

**What I'm trying to do?**

- every time I select a new type (from type options) - I want the country and city fields to be reset.
- every time I already search the same key (the queryKey is combined of cacheKey+inputValue) , it will not call to api, it will get the results from cache (that's what I chose to use from react-query to do).

**What I'm getting when I run my code?**

- When I select a type A, enter a country “Island” it will fetch data from api and get the data.
  Then when I select a type B, enter a country “Island” - It will fetch data from api and get the data.
  But when I select a type A and and same country “Island” again - I don’t want it to fetch data from api - I want it to get data from cache (that’s the reason I chose to work with react-query too) because it already search for this data with the same type. The queryKey is depended of other type field.
- when I search anything from autocomplete and it not find it, then I try to reset it by select any other type, it will kind of reset the value of the input but it still exist in inputValue of the country.
  for example I select type C, then enter "lakd" in country, then select any other type, it not reset it. reset works for me only when anything find in autocomplete and I select it. I guess it's because the autocomplete component not have inputValue props, but when I use it it make me other issues.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first issue, I think it would be better to use enable property of react-query(to handle it with debounceInputValue).

so you can use boolean state for enable and disable it  and in `useEffect` for `debounceInputValue` make it true but when data arrived make it false again

sth like this :

```
  const [queryStatus, setQueryStatus] = useState(false);

 const { data, isFetching, refetch } = useQueryData(
    cacheKey,
    inputValue,
    queryAsyncFunc,
    queryStatus
  );

  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (debounceInputValue.length > 1) {
      setQueryStatus(true);
    }
  }, [debounceInputValue]);


  useEffect(() => {
    setDataOptions(data ? [...data] : []);
    setQueryStatus(false);
  }, [inputValue, data]);
```

and in useQuery:

```
enabled: enabled,
staleTime: Infinity,
```

And for your second issue, I fixed it by setting state  for inputValue and onChange for it

like this :

```
  const onInputChange = (_,newInputValue)=>{
    setInputValue(newInputValue);
  }
```

and in autoComplete :

```
 inputValue={inputValue}
 onInputChange={onInputChange}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-autocomplete-forked-efkrqh?file=/src/components/FormFields/AutocompleteField.tsx)

Comment: Hey, when you select type then select country that exist, it will call twice to api, look it make loading twice..

Comment: I check it, it just call the api only once !!

Comment: I logged sth in handleSearchCountry function, and it works as expected.
see this : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-autocomplete-forked-efkrqh?file=/src/components/AddressSection.tsx

Comment: do this scenario: select type c, then enter country "isla" then select any country, it show loading again, it means it make refetch twice

Comment: you can check the network too.. when you select any country it call api again.. first it call when you search then when you select any country it call again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251809/discussion-between-manspof-and-ali-sattarzadeh).

Comment: did u see the issue?

Comment: yes, I saw it, I'm working on it

Comment: check this one : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-autocomplete-forked-efkrqh?file=/src/components/FormFields/CacheAutocompleteField.tsx:3553-3554

is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: it's crash when select type then enter any country then select type again "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'target')
"

Comment: aha, check this one : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-autocomplete-forked-efkrqh?file=/src/components/FormFields/CacheAutocompleteField.tsx

Comment: happy to hear that, your welcome

Comment: @ Ali Sattarzadeh is there any way to limit the text field length to 5 for example? I did with inputProps = {{maxLength:4}} into the textField but not working as expected

Comment: actually I tried this way but didn't work (I don't know why) but I did it with a trick. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-autocomplete-forked-efkrqh?file=/src/components/AddressSection.tsx

Comment: that's great, just last thing.. can we make an error message when he tried to put more than 4 chars? like the required but just to limit (maybe to remove max length but the error message is more important for me)

Comment: do you have any idea how can I show an error message of max limit for those fields? I tried with formik.setFieldError but it not override the required message

Comment: Hi, I don't think that you can do it with formik or yup because the structure of the code is different. but I did sth that code help you. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-autocomplete-forked-efkrqh?file=/src/components/FormFields/AutocompleteField.tsx

Comment: @ Ali Sattarzadeh , in this case, if I will press on submit form and max length show error, it will understand that I have error because the limit? or it just display error? :) maybe I thought to change the structure of the yup field to be {label,value,text}. the search field of textInput will be only with text.. something like that but I guess it too complicated

Comment: maybe something like that:   country: Yup.object().shape({
    value: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    label: Yup.string(),
    text: Yup.string().max(50, 'Must be 50 characters or less')
  }),

Answer (score -2):

You needn't call `refetch`. It call the API regardless of the cache.
Comment/Remove this code

```
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (debounceInputValue.length > 1) {
  //     refetch();
  //   }
  // }, [debounceInputValue, refetch]);
```

And you should enable the `useQuery`

```
enabled: true,
```

And use `debounceInputValue` instead of `inputValue` for `useQueryData`

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-autocomplete-forked-d84rf4?file=/src/components/FormFields/CacheAutocompleteField.tsx:1255-1263

Comment: it's not working... it refetch again when I select different type.. please check, select type A, then type "Island", then select different type - type B, it will refetch automatically - look in the inputs it will make refetch (it's bug)

Comment: it refetch automatically because the key of the cacheKey (select type) is changed and the queryName has changed so it see different key.. it not should be like that

Comment: you did a change in main logic, you changed queryKey to be only debounceParams, but it's not what I want.. I want it to be depend on cacheKey param too because lets take an example (it's not my real api I put in the link code but it's kind of): if I select Type A, then type Island, then select Type B then type Island, it will not refetch again - not good for me because in my real api I  send Type and country to server and it filtered to me based them so if types are different so it should so different results. you get my point?

Comment: if I changed the queryKey to be as it was before: [cacheKey,debounceParams] - the issue still reproduce

Comment: I think that you will need to make additional logic in the useQueryData. Something like saving oldCacheKey.

Comment: that's not what react-query should do for me?

Comment: react-query call queryFn whenever queryKey is changed. But you want to put [cacheKey,debounceParams] as the queryKey. Your requirement is the issue. So, you have to make additional logic in the queryFn function for your requirement.

Comment: yes, that's true but because that I tried to use with refetch to call queryFn manually.. you think we can do it with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251561/discussion-between-manspof-and-andrii).

Comment: ok I fixed the issue by using getQueryData of react-query, you can use it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-autocomplete-forked-lpyukw?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I just have the issue with the reset field, for example if you type country "sasas", it will not find you any results, then you try to reset it by select other type, country value field will stay "sasas"